# ChartJS date formating

Tags: javascript, date, chart.js

I am trying to make a graph that shows how much power solarpanels are produsing using chartJS. I am using data in the following format

`{x: Fri Mar 19 2021 06:20:28 GMT+0100 (centraleuropeisk normaltid), y: 1.88}`

And it makes a graph but the x values is not in a readable date format. The graph liks like this:

Link to picture of graph (I am not allowed to post images yet apparently)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtFgN.png

To make the graph I use this code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart");
  var line = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "scatter",
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          data: power,
          borderColor: "#ffd420",
          showLine: true,
          fill: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      tooltips: { enabled: false },
      hover: { mode: null },
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 0,
        },
      },
      //---
      xAxes: [],
      //--
    },
  });
```

I have tried to play with the xAxes settings but it still show a large number instead of a date.
Does anyone know what settings can fix this or do I need to change the format of the input?
I have searched alot but I can't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222136/2358409

Comment: @uminder I still have some formating problems. The format I get is '2021-03-19 15:55:00' and I want to format hh:mm, but i get an error message when formatting `xAxes: [{type: "time", time: {unit: "minute", tooltipFormat: "h:mm a", }, },],` but what I can understand that is how you would format time acc to https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source

Comment: This may help: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, you can make use of the timescale provided by chart.js in here you can set what format you want it to show the dates: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

The other options is to use the tick callback to do it yourself like this:

```
options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        const date = new Date(value)
                        return `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getFullYear()}`
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```